# clone succeeded but checkout failed

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, parallels

I tried to clone a large project at work.  It has worked in the past.  This is a new machine I'm working on and I'm cloning it using terminal on the Mac in one of the /Volumes folder where Parallels can access it.  Previously, I have cloned it on Windows no problem.

An error I get when it's done is it says,

```
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

When I try to do the git checkout -f HEAD, it looks like git tries to check it out, but it basically goes through the different projects in the VS solution saying:

```
error: unable to create file src/MyProject (File exists)
```

Has anyone encountered this before?  Is it because I'm trying to clone to /Volumes/c/MyProjects/NameOfProject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "`You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'`" Ok: What `git status` says? And what is your version of git?

Answer (score -1):

I've encounter this error before.

The files from the repo are present(successfully cloned) but it only failed to do a checkout.

Remove the files.